# How to set initial value for variable in Openresty

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, openresty

1. What I want

I am using `openresty stream`, I want to set an variable in `nginx.conf`, and `lua` file can visit this variable.

2. What have I tried

I have tried `lua_add_variable`, but it seems that `lua_add_variable` can not set initial value.

I also tried `set $var value`, but I got error:`"set" directive is not allowed here` , I think `set` can not be used in `stream`

3. my codes

   ```
    nginx.conf

    stream {
        # lua_add_variable $servers_list "client1;client2";
        # set $servers_list "client1;client2"; # set not allowed here

        upstream backend {
            server 127.0.0.1:666;
        }
        server {
            lua_code_cache off;
            listen 65;
            preread_by_lua_file lua/echo.lua;
            content_by_lua_block {
                ngx.say("nerver reach here")
            }
        }

   }

   echo.lua

   ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "list is ", ngx.var.servers_list) -- I want to get "client1;client2" here
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` directive is available for the stream subsystem — https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_set_module.html#set — but in the `server` context block only:

> Context:  `server`

To fix the following error:

> "set" directive is not allowed here

move the directive to the `server` context block:

```
server {
    set $servers_list "client1;client2";
    lua_code_cache off;
    ...
```